# Google Bigquery, getting beginning and end of the week for a particular time zone

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Assuming that the week begins on a Sunday morning (00:00:00) and ends on Saturday night (23:59:59). 
Given a particular time zone (ex: 'CST6CDT'), I want to get the corresponding UTC times for beginning and end at this time zone.

Example: 
For this week and time zone 'CST6CDT',

Beginning of the week @CST6CDT =  24th November, 00:00:00  corresponds to 24th November, 06:00:00 @UTC 
End of the week @CST6CDT = 30th November, 23:59:59  which corresponds to  1st December, 05:59:59 @UTC

I need to get the beginning and end time @UTC as shown above which will be used to extract data. Would really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK), 'CST6CDT') AS start_week, 
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), 'CST6CDT'), INTERVAL 1 SECOND) AS end_week
```

with result

```
Row start_week              end_week     
1   2019-11-24 06:00:00 UTC 2019-12-01 05:59:59 UTC
```

Obviously, you can refactor above for easy reuse as in example below, so you can pass any date of your interest into UDF

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION week_boundary(day DATE) AS (
  STRUCT(
  TIMESTAMP(DATE_TRUNC(day, WEEK), 'CST6CDT') AS start_week, 
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(day, WEEK), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), 'CST6CDT'), INTERVAL 1 SECOND) AS end_week
  )
);
SELECT week_boundary(CURRENT_DATE()).*
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail!  This is exactly what I've been trying to achieve. Don't think I need the UDF right now, as the only input is a time zone and day will always be the current_day. With the calculated start & end dates I have to extract data, so I'm always looking at data for a specific time zone. This is perfect!

Comment: sure, come back and vote up the answer when you have enough reputation :o)

Comment: Haha. Will do !